# iframe src to be massaged by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

To say that I am a novice in javascript is an insult to a novice.  Even my limited HTML knowledge is self-taught.  Here's my problem:  I am trying to massage the src in a simple iframe, like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function embedKey() {
var url = window.location.href;
var symbol = url.split('?')[1];
if(symbol=="INNO"){
  uniqueKey = "&resid=27A14C5DE396792C%21235&authkey=ANDfOBKrOKskLqg"
  return "https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=27A14C5DE396792C" + uniqueKey +"&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&ActiveCell='Sheet1'!B3&wdHideGridlines=True&wdHideHeaders=True"
}
else {
  alert(url);
  return false;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe width="402" height="346" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src=javascript:embedKey();></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I will be adding many more conditions/symbols/return strings to the embedKey() function.  Right now, I am trying to make it work with one.

Comment: Does it end up calling the `embedKey()` function?  What does the function return?

Comment: It results in an empty iframe box right now.  when I tested the result of the function return by insert an ALERT() at the end of the function, the return value seems to be correct.  I just don't seem to be able to get it to apply in the iframe. IN other words, the function seems to work correctly.

Comment: Realizing the point of the previous question, it does not appear to call the embedKey() function at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JavaScript gets executed from a `src` attribute like that.  With something like an `href` attribute on an `a` element (where one often sees inline JavaScript) there's at least a click event to respond to, but not in this case.

Instead of trying to call the function inline from the element like that, call it from a script block after the element has loaded.  Something like this:

```
<iframe width="402" height="346" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="someIframe"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('someIframe').src = embedKey();
</script>
```

Comment: That did the trick David, thanks.  Seems silly though.  It should have worked my way.  It would have been more elegant to use it inline.

Comment: @user2604849: Not really.  Inline JavaScript is very much frowned upon as an inelegant solution all around.  Ideally the JavaScript should be completely separated from the HTML.  Both serve very different purposes and belong in entirely different places.  The HTML should represent the content, and the JavaScript loaded separately to act on that content.  As any codebase grows, keeping those concerns separated results in much cleaner and easier to maintain code.